# What algorithm can I use for Task management app project proposal and how can I make it happen?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am a beginner in programming and currently learning design and analysis of algorithm. We are tasked to create an app that focuses on a specific algorithm. Our group decided to do a task management app or those apps that helps you be productive by sorting your schedule in the most efficient manner. I am just wondering on what algorithm/s should I use for this to make it happen and what steps should I follow to make it happen?

As of the moment, we do have few algorithms in our list but we don't know what to use. also, in terms of coding, we are a group of students that are not that good in programming, so suggestions and tips in doing our project would be very much appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to first think about what is an "efficiently sorted schedule", in purely non-programming terms, I'd say.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the requirements, I would say this sounds like something that could fall into the usage of a bucket and merge sort algorithm. You might want to look more into those and see if it fits your criteria. Otherwise, you might want to give more requirements. Usually, this group is here to help you through a specific problem, not a full assignment.

Comment: We are considering Heuristics and Greedy algorithm for our supposed project, would they be efficient to use? Our project is supposed to help students schedule their mini  tasks in between their class schedules. Thank you!